# How to convert system for Runge Kutta integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I have the following two equations ($a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are constants)

$$\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}=-a-b\sin(c-x_{2})$$

$$(d+x_{1}^{3})\frac{d^{2}x_{2}}{dt^{2}}+ex_{1}^{2}\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}=f(g-x_{1}^{2})\cos (x_{2})$$

and want to integrate it numerically as an initial value problem.

Is the right way to convert this into a first order system of ordinary differential equations (for Runge Kutta integration say) to have 4 first order equations for $x_{1},dx_{1}/dt,x_{2},dx_{2}/dt$? This would mean having to differentiate the first equation above to generate $d^{2}x_{1}/dt^{2}$.

Or  the right way is to have 3 first order equations for $x_{1},x_{2},dx_{2}/dt$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's introduce $$x_3 = \frac{dx_2}{dt}.$$ Then:

$$(d+x_{1}^{3})\frac{d^{2}x_{2}}{dt^{2}}+ex_{1}^{2}\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}\frac{dx_{2}}{dt}=f(g-x_{1}^{2})\cos (x_{2}) = \\
(d+x_{1}^{3})\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}+ex_{1}^{2}\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}x_3=f(g-x_{1}^{2})\cos (x_{2}).
$$

Isolating $\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}$ on the left, you get:

$$\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}=\frac{f(g-x_{1}^{2})\cos (x_{2}) - ex_{1}^{2}\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}x_3}{d+x_{1}^{3}} \Rightarrow \\
\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}=\frac{f(g-x_{1}^{2})\cos (x_{2}) - ex_{1}^{2}\left(-a-b\sin(c-x_{2})\right)x_3}{d+x_{1}^{3}}.
$$

Finally, your system of first order differential equations is:

$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{dx_{1}}{dt}=-a-b\sin(c-x_{2})\\
\displaystyle\frac{dx_2}{dt} = x_3\\
\displaystyle\frac{dx_{3}}{dt}=\frac{f(g-x_{1}^{2})\cos (x_{2}) - ex_{1}^{2}\left(-a-b\sin(c-x_{2})\right)x_3}{d+x_{1}^{3}}
\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have to harmonize the order of differentiation of the variable. You only need to address the derivatives that actually occur.

Thus using `x1,x2,Dx2` as variables you can evaluate

```
Dx1 = -a−b*sin(c−x2)
D2x2 = (-e*x1^2*Dx1*Dx2+f*(g−x1^2)*cos(x2))/(d+x1^3)
```

and return `Dx1, Dx2, D2x2` as derivative vector.